# Block user from executing .bat files accidentally

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

We've large number of bat files in our server and they're scheduled using task scheduler. Sometimes, instead of right click to edit it, users execute them by double clicking it, triggering processes.

> 1. Can I able to change the double click properties of batch files only? Like triple click to execute, double click to do nothing.
> 2. Are there any batch commands to prompt user when they try to execute directly instead of command line?

Comment: Are there differences in the environment depending on how you start it? That's what I'd do on Linux ...

Comment: @o11c DIfferences in environment? I'm afraid I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Run `set` to get a list of environment variables in each shell - probably redirect both to a file so you can diff them at your leisure. There are other environment-specific things besides variables (e.g. "is the output redirected to a file?"), but I don't know them all on Windows.

Comment: `set "_is.c="&for /f "tokens=*" %%# in ("%ComSpec%") do for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%c in ('echo %CmdCmdLine%') do if /i "%%~nc"=="%%~n#" if /i "%%~d"=="/c" set "_is.c=1"` `if defined _is.c notepad "%~0"& goto :eof` tested on win xp/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar cases and the issue solved when I added in the begin of the script `TIMEOUT 10` the batch starts after 10 seconds, so if someone will accidentally start it will have time to close the window without running.

I do not recommend it but you can break the associated application for .bat files from registry changing the (Default) value from `"%1" %*` to `nothing` of the key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command`

I would definitely choose the first option.

Comment: does registry change affect the way it is started from task scheduler?

Comment: No, the scheduled jobs will still be working even you have broken the associated application. (Tested in Windows 10 Pro)

Comment: Thanks @Wolf Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
    @echo off &::in_con.bat filename and args
    setlocal
    set "_is.c=0"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%# in ("%ComSpec%") do for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%c in ('echo %CmdCmdLine%') do if /i "%%~nc"=="%%~n#" if /i "%%~d"=="/c" set "_is.c=1"
    rem if running by click open in notepad
    if "%_is.c%"=="1" if exist "%~1" notepad "%~1"
    rem if running in console pass it throuth
    endlocal & if "%_is.c%"=="0" cmd /c %*
    goto :eof
```

always run .bat throuth `cmd /c in_con.bat`

Comment: Can you explain what these exactly do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just rename them all to `.txt` and in your scheduler copy the file to a `.bat|.cmd` file and execute it.  Best of all worlds.

Comment: I have numerous bat files running 24/7 fetching and updating data into the database, doing copy and pasting file contents may cause performance issues right?